# Hbase Table migration to Google Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

I have 500TB size HBase table in our on-premise Hadoop cluster. How can we migrate this HBase data to Google Bigtable. Any suggestion will be appreciated. We have 10 Gbps network connection between on-premise to google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to perform an offline migration (stop your writes) the there is a [thorough guide](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data-hbase-to-bigtable) and suite of tools to help with that. On the Bigtable team we've recently added support for migrating [using snapshots](https://github.com/billyjacobson/java-bigtable-hbase/blob/5d1e61c004692e857ce8f17c3657926e0a3962b5/bigtable-dataflow-parent/bigtable-beam-import/README.md) and the guide will be updated for that shortly. If you're looking to do an online migration we have a [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkTPEDhhS1c) that goes into the details of what needs to be done for that. Let me know if this helps or if you can provide more information on your situation.

Comment: Hi Billy,
Thank you for your response, we need to transfer HBase table data to GCP online using dedicated network connection,
My only concern is volume of HBase table which around 500 TB. Exporting entire tabe to sequence file or creating snaphot may not be suitable. 
I was thinking to export HBase table data split wise or Column Family wise but I didnot see any utility in HBase which can do that . 
Would you please guide me on this. Is it possible to export 500TB size table to file at a time (on premise Hadoop cluster may have enough space for this) and move to GCP and the load to BQ.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Billy said, we also have a [validation job](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/tree/bigtable-1.x/bigtable-dataflow-parent/bigtable-beam-import#validating-data), that works with Apache [HBase Hashtable job (Point 4)](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/tree/bigtable-1.x/bigtable-dataflow-parent/bigtable-beam-import#exporting-snapshots-from-hbase). This validation job compares hashes between HBase and Bigtable and matches them. If there are no mismatches, you can be assured that all the data was copied without any issues.

You can also create a pre-split table in Cloud Bigtable based on your HBase table using our [Schema translation tool](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/tree/bigtable-1.x/bigtable-hbase-1.x-parent/bigtable-hbase-1.x-tools#hbase-tools).

Comment: Hi Verma, Thank you for your response, we need to transfer HBase table data to GCP online using dedicated network connection, My only concern is volume of HBase table which around 500 TB. Exporting entire tabe to sequence file or creating snaphot may not be suitable. I was thinking to export HBase table data split wise or Column Family wise but I did not see any utility in HBase which can do that . Would you please guide me on this. Is it possible to export 500TB size table to file at a time (on premise Hadoop cluster may have enough space for this) and move to GCP and the load to BQ.

Comment: When you take a snapshot, it takes minimal space at first. As HBase snapshot just pin the HFiles used for serving your workload. As time progresses and snapshot deviates from the live table, it starts taking more space. For migration purposes, exporting a snapshot should not require much additional space on 
 you cluster. Please reach out to us via a GCP support and we can guide you further. You can ask the support person to route the request to Dev team.